# SQL Server JSON Transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, pivot, open-json

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json='{"name":"John","surname":"Doe","age":45,"skills":["SQL","C#","MVC"]}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

This gives you
key,     value, and type as Columns.

I want to have Name, surname and age as columns.
and the row would be John, Doe, 45.

How do I flip or transpose the columns and rows?
I've tried pivot but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `with` clause of `openjson()`:

```
select * 
from openjson(@json) with (
    name nvarchar(max), 
    surname nvarchar(max), 
    age int
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7a5a316e9d358de2ad51ed20a65efb8)**:

```
name | surname | age
:--- | :------ | --:
John | Doe     |  45
```